# Can you watch the Butterfly Effect Movies out of order?

Tags: suggested-order, the-butterfly-effect

So I read the previews of all three *Butterfly Effect* movies and they all seem to be separate stories about separate people with separate ways of travelling through time. Does this mean that you can watch any *Butterfly Effect* movie without needing context from the other two and not having spoilers for the other two?

Comment: Yes, you can, but it alters the outcome of the movies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Butterfly_Effect#Sequels), and which I can bear out from experience, the movies are all completely unrelated to each other other than in that they all involve characters who can travel back in time to a prior point in their life to try to change things, only to find that their changes have consequences. The only tie between the movies is "a brief reference to the first film in the form of a newspaper headline referring to Evan's father" in *The Butterfly Effect 2*.

So yes, you can watch the movies out of order. I'd personally recommend watching the first one only and skipping the sequels.